# UITableView not working properly as last few rows are hidden behind screen and not coming up

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have made a UITableViewCell but the last few rows are not showing up properly as they are hidden behind the screen and when I scroll up forcibly then cells are been seen but when I release the finger from the screen it again gets hide. What should I do to make all the cells visible properly like normal talbeveiwCells?

Comment: Have you made UITableView by storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: Can you share a video of what you are trying to explain? Not clear what you mean by "not coming up properly"

Comment: Check your tableview constraints.

Comment: thank @MohitKumar this helps me alot

Comment: no @Aditya i made it through storyboard

Comment: thanks to everyone for giving your  time

Comment: @abhishek is that resolved?

Comment: ya that is resolved brother. i have made a mistake in constraints